# Laravel count function

Tags: php, laravel, count

I have a small lms app with a few models and controllers as Ecourse, Lesson and Lecture.

Each Ecourse can have many Lessons and each Lesson can have many Lectures.

If I want to know how many lectures an ecourse has I can do it with `{{ $ecourse->lessons->count() }}` and it works fine.

Same with `{{ $lesson->lectures->count() }}` to see how many lectures a lesson has.

But what I reall want, is to display the number of Lectures in an Ecourse.

I tried this `{{ $ecourse->lessons->lectures->count() }}`, but of course it does not work.

I get this error message :

> Property [lectures] does not exist on this collection instance.

So now I'm lost.

How can I make this work?

Thanks a lot

Peace

Edit :

Ecourse model :

```
public function lessons()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Lesson');
}
```

Lesson model :

```
public function ecourse()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Ecourse');
}

public function lectures()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Lecture');
}
```

Lecture model :

```
public function lesson()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Lesson');
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: can u add your model relationship as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try get the relation the get sum of the counts ...

```
$lectures_count=  $ecourse->lessons()->withCount('lectures')->get()->sum('lectures_count');
```

Comment: Thanks @OMR ! It worked ! I've inserted the whole code in my index.blade view file. Is it the right way to dit?

Comment: if you build like @vinod (has-many-through) it would be better, but i choose the simplest approach

Answer (score 0):

The `has-many-through` relationship provides a convenient shortcut for accessing distant relations via an intermediate relation. In your case you can use this like:

In `Ecourse` Model Define `lectures()`

```
public function lectures()
{
     return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Lecture', 'App\Lesson');
}
```

The first argument passed to the `hasManyThrough` method is the name of the final model we wish to access, while the second argument is the name of the intermediate model.

And to get count of lecture you can simply do this:

```
{{ $ecourse->lectures->count() }}
```

Comment: Thanks @vinod and OMR. Both solutions work and I decided to with vinod's. I wish I could mark both answers as the best solution ! Thanks again for your time. Stay safe. Peace